# Sort arrays with pointers using quicksort

Tags: c, pointers, quicksort

I'm trying to sort the values in the array "tab" using quicksort, but it isn't working. the main function just set names and salaries for each tab[n]

```
typedef struct employee Employee;

struct employee{
  char name[81];
  float salary;
};

Employee *tab[10];

void sort(Employee **tab, int begin, int end){
  int p = tab[(begin + end) / 2] , i = end, j = begin;  
  /*p is the pivot*/
  do{
    while(tab[i]->salary < p && i < end) i++; 
    while(tab[j]->salary > p && j > begin) j--; 

    if(i <= j){
      int tmp = tab[i]->salary;
      tab[i]->salary = tab[j]->salary;
      tab[j]->salary = tmp;
      i++; j--;
    }
  }while(i <= j);

  if(begin < j) sort(tab, begin, j);
  if(end > i) sort(tab, i, end);
}
```

Comment: your pivot `p` is `Employee*`, not `int`

Comment: In what way isn't it working?  What size of array is it failing on (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, more elements)?  What is the sample data that it is failing on?  What is the `Employee` structure looking like?  Why are you only swapping salaries and not the whole employee records?  The person whose name comes first ends up with the lowest salary, ad the person whose name comes last ends up with the highest salary?  Or vice versa?

Comment: Thanks for that much extra information.  However, you've not discussed how it is failing, nor have you shown how you're loading the array of pointers with valid pointers and loading the pointed at structures with data.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses;
MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Why can't you use `qsort`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't it be **float** p = tab[(begin + end) / 2] **->salary**?  In the 2 while loops that follow you are comparing a float (tab[i]->salary and tab[j]->salary) to an int (p) which (as mangusta points out) in turn has been equated to a structure element pointer, You should swap the i and j th structure elements, not just the salary.

Comment: @JL2210 indeed, unless this is an exercise in writing your own quicksort routine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [I fully agree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389071/can-we-change-mre-back-to-mcve).

Comment: You get my up-vote @JL2210 but I'm not sure we'll win in the long run.  Sometime in 5 years time or so I may stop using that version (it's a precanned sequence I copy'n'paste, not something I type ab initio whenever I need it).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Where do you keep those?

Comment: @JL2210: I keep them on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) repository — in the [`src/scripts`](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/scripts) directory.  This one is `sscce`.  I work on Macs mostly, so `sscce | sed 5q | pbcopy` gives me the text quoted above in the paste buffer, and command-V (⌘-V) puts it into the comment. The other links in lines 6+ are: _See also
[How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes noted in comments. This is a descending order sort (as asked in a follow up question).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct employee{
    char name[81];
    float salary;
}Employee;

void sort(Employee **tab, int begin, int end){
    float p = tab[(begin + end) / 2]->salary; /* float needed for compare == */
    int i = begin, j = end;
    Employee *tmp;                          /* microsoft is c89 */

    while(i <= j){                      /* using while */
        while(tab[i]->salary > p) i++;  /* >, <= pivot stops scan */
        while(tab[j]->salary < p) j--;  /* <, >= pivot stops scan */
        if(i > j)                       /* using break */
            break;
        tmp = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tab[j];
        tab[j] = tmp;
        i++; j--;
    }

    if(begin < j) sort(tab, begin, j);
    if(end > i) sort(tab, i, end);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    Employee tab[] = {{"john", 525.}, {"jack", 520.},
                      {"mary", 537.}, {"jane", 523.},
                      {"joan", 548.}, {"sam",  524.},
                      {"lisa", 527.}, {"ann",  541.},
                      {"tom",  521.}, {"ted",  531.}};
    Employee *ptr[sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0])];
    int i;
    /* create array of pointers */
    for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0])); i++)
        ptr[i] = &tab[i];
    sort(ptr, 0, sizeof(ptr)/sizeof(ptr[0])-1);
    for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(ptr)/sizeof(ptr[0])); i++)
        printf("%5s %6.2f\n", ptr[i]->name, ptr[i]->salary);
    return 0;
}
```